# Cannot deactivate record type because it is referenced by other entities

Tags: community, account, record-type, sales

I am attempting to deactivate an account record type in my Salesforce org, which is not referenced by any Profiles, Apex Classes, or Flows/Process Builders. When I attempt to deactivate, I receive the error message

> "This record type Carrier - Air cannot be deactivated because it is
>   referenced by other entities."

However, when I click on the link provided, it dumps me onto a Classic page that states I have insufficient privileges to access. It seems to point to an object that doesn't exist, with the URL being `/lightning/r/FieldBasedPAC/09pr000000000cbAAA/view`

Answer (score 11):

I finally found the answer to this after hours of searching. This happens when you have setup a **community audience** that references the record type you are attempting to deactivate. It seems as though the platform isn't able to route you to the audience as the reference that is invalid, and I couldn't find any documentation on the FieldBasedPAC object, which I am assuming is part of the community audience framework. I hope this helps someone who had this same issue!

Comment: Nice find. Thank you for sharing your insight with a good first question!